# Extra lines drawn by Axes.plot in matplotlib when passing odd number of lines

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw pairs of points and connect them with lines. Here is a minimal example with two pairs of points and two lines:

```
points = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]]
line_list  = [[[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

scatter = ax.scatter(*list(zip(*points)))
lines = ax.plot(*line_list)

plt.show()
```

This works as I would expect:

[image]

Next, I'd like to add another pair of points, and an extra line connecting them:

```
points = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 2.5], [0.5, 3.5]]
line_list = [[[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]], [[0, 2.5], [0.5, 3.5]]]
```

Executing the same matplotlib code as above, I get this unexpected result with the third line terminating in the wrong point, and an extra fourth line:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. My initial thought was that I have the line array being passed to Axes.plot somehow malformed, but the confusing part is that it works in the two-line example.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I can't figure out why `ax.plot` does behave in this manner.
In particular I am puzzled that `ax.plot` draw a line starting from `(0, 0)` even if that that point is not present at all in any of the lists you provided.

*However*, you can draw the plot you want with:

```
for line in line_list: ax.plot(*zip(*line))
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


points = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 2.5], [0.5, 3.5]]
line_list = [[[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]], [[0, 2.5], [0.5, 3.5]]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.scatter(*zip(*points))
for line in line_list: ax.plot(*zip(*line))

plt.show()
```

[image]

(notice that I simplified `ax.scatter(*list(zip(*points)))` in `ax.scatter(*zip(*points))`)